# expect complains that send: spawn id exp6 not open

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I use a script to automatically login with Telnet and run some commands on the remote device.
But the below code snippet does not work now and then.

Here is the said script:

```
        expect << EOS
        log_user 0;
        spawn telnet 192.168.1.51 -l root

        expect "#"
        send "ls; pwd;\r"
                log_user 1;
        expect "#"
                log_user 0;
        send "exit\r"
        expect eof
EOS
```

Here is the output when the code snippet above works well:

```
ls; pwd;
testprogram
/root
```

Here is the output when something wrong occurs:

```
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "ls; pwd;\r""
```

Then I try to run with `expect -d` to get extra debugging output.

Here is the output when `-d` is enabled:

```
expect version 5.45.3
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -d  
set argc 0
set argv0 "expect"
set argv ""
executing commands from command file
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {95242}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "#"? no

expect: does "Trying 192.168.1.51...\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "#"? no

expect: does "Trying 192.168.1.51...\r\nConnected to 192.168.1.51.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "#"? no

expect: does "Trying 192.168.1.51...\r\nConnected to 192.168.1.51.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\nConnection closed by foreign host.\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "#"? no
expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Trying 192.168.1.51...\r\nConnected to 192.168.1.51.\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\nConnection closed by foreign host.\r\n"
send: sending "ls; pwd;\r" to { exp6 send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "ls; pwd;\r""
```

***UPDATED check `Connection closed by foreign host.`***

Thanks to @glenn jackman,sincerely.

I added `expect_before` to match `Connection closed by foreign host.` once `expect` is called. But one more problem arises, this script will print out `Telnet session closed unexpectedly. Please try again.` even when this script successfully finishes its work and then called `send "exit\r"; expect eof`.

***Is there any way to make the `expect_before` not work anymore when the last `expect` command(i.e. `expect eof`) is to be invoked?***

Simply removing the `expect eof` seems a way to achieve this goal. But as far as I can see, it's not a good solution.

```
expect  << EOS
        log_user 0;
        spawn telnet 192.168.1.51 -l root

        expect_before {
                     "Connection closed by foreign host." {
                           puts "Telnet session closed unexpectedly."
                           puts "Please try again."
                           exit
                      }
                      exp_continue
                  }
        
        expect "#"
        send "ls; pwd;\r"
        log_user 1;
        expect "#"
        log_user 0;
        send "exit\r"
        expect eof
EOS
```

Here is the output when this script successfully finishes its work (and then called `send "exit\r"; expect eof`):

```
ls; pwd;
testprogram
/root
# Telnet session closed unexpectedly.
Please try again.
```

Comment: Telnet is reporting "Connection closed by foreign host.". It looks like you'll need to write your script to be robust in the face of connection failures: perhaps a retry loop of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the "Connection closed by foreign host."

```
spawn telnet 192.168.1.51 -l root

expect {
    "Connection closed by foreign host." {
        puts "Telnet session closed unexpectedly."
        puts "Please try again."
        exit
    }
    "#"
}
```

With this form of the `expect` command, expect is looking for **two** patterns, and the first one found "wins".

- if "connection closed" happens, the messages are printed and the program ends
- if "#" (your prompt) shows up, there's no specific action, so the `expect` command returns and the rest of your program can carry on

This technique is essential for efficient expect programming where you frequently have to look for multiple patterns.

---

Looking forward, you might expect to see "Connection closed" at any time: investigate the `expect_before` command.

Comment: Sorry, I may misunderstand you. [It  seems not work](http://tpcg.io/_Q3W9JG), which makes the script ***always waits*** for `Connection closed by foreign host` when the connection is all right. **And** why there is a `"#"` in your script?

Comment: Thank you so much. You save a day! Is there any way to make the `expect_before` not work anymore when the last `expect` command(i.e. `expect eof`) is to be invoked? For the details, see the ***session*** named `UPDATED check Connection closed by foreign host.` in the post.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but either `expect_before` (with no arguments) or `expect_before {}` will erase the current before patterns.

Comment: Yup! Both `excpect_before` without any argument and `expect_before {}` could achieve this goal. Thank you so much!